# kubectl logs not working, all other commands working

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

On kubernetes 1.5.2 all of sudden **kubectl logs** is showing error while other commands are working fine, so definitely there is no issue with cluster setup but possibly some sort of bug. Kindly advise if there is workaround to get the logs working.

```
$ kubectl logs -f some-pod-name
```

Error is given below:

```
**Error from server: Get https://Minion-1-IP:10250/containerLogs/default/some-pod-name-3851540691-b18vp/some-pod-name?follow=true: net/http: TLS handshake timeout**
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the cluster setup. This error message doesn't come from the connection between `kubectl` and the apiserver, rather than between the apiserver and the kubelets. Therefore the certificates between these two might not be correct.

*Disclaimer:* I can't verify this idea right now, but we had a similar problem a while ago.

Comment: Hi @svenwltr, thanks for responding. Actually the same command was working last night, so I'm not sure how could this be a cluster setup issue. Please if you can assist to get it working through some workaround.

Comment: Can you do `curl https://Minion-1-IP:10250/containerLogs/default/some-pod-name-3851540691-b18vp/some-pod-name?follow=true` from the Kubernetes master?

Comment: Yes able to curl the logs endpoint for Minion and is returning Server certificate:
curl -v -k https://Minion-1-IP:10250/containerLogs/default/some-pod-nam‌​e-3851540691-b18vp/s‌​ome-pod-name?follow=‌​true

Comment: Also have tried to validate the SSL handshake using openssl s_client -msg -connect MINION_IP:PORT and it returns server and client hello msgs correctly. But what i noticed it takes around 30s to exchange the SSL certs, so basically kubectl is timing out between 5-10 seconds. I have tried to increase timeout for kubelet communication by adding  --kubelet-timeout 60s to kube-apiserver ARGS but still it's timing out within 5-10 seconds. So it means kubelet-timeout option is not working as expected.

Comment: This sounds very slow. Any idea why it takes so long? Are these nodes in the same network? Is the worker node to small? Is there a load balancer in between which runs into a timeout?

Comment: Not sure on slowness as this was working since last night. Yes these are in same network. Worker node has sufficient CPU and Memory as i can see still 10 Gig RAM free. There is no load balancer between master and worker nodes. Is there a way to increase this timeout between Master and worker?

Comment: Maybe [`--kubelet-timeout duration`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/) on the apiserver helps, but I also would investigate about the slowness.

Answer (score 4):

In short, for me, the problem is caused by misconfigured proxy.

I came across this very same symptom last week. After poking around for some time This [ISSUE](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/211) showed up.

For me, It's because I initialized the cluster with

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://10.196.109.214:8118 HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.196.109.214:8118 NO_PROXY=10.196.109.214,localhost,127.0.0.1 kubeadm init
```

`10.196.109.214` is my master node and on which I set up an http proxy. The proxy settings are automatically written in kubernete manifists. NO_PROXY here does not include any worker nodes, so that cause everything works fine but I can't retrieve any log from workers.

I just hand edited the env part of `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-*.yaml` and add worker nodes' ips:

```
env:
- name: NO_PROXY
  value: 10.196.109.214,10.196.109.215,10.196.109.216,10.196.109.217,localhost,127.0.0.1
- name: HTTP_PROXY
  value: http://10.196.109.214:8118
- name: HTTPS_PROXY
  value: http://10.196.109.214:8118
```

Then find relative pods with `kubectl -n kube-system get pods` and delete them with `kubectl -n kube-system delete pod <pod-name>`, wait for them to be recreated by kubelet. Everything works fine now.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to one of our customers. We added a new node, it operated fine, but certain commands to the node didn't work, such as fetching logs.